# Fetching records from recrusive has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, associations

I stuck with puzzle. I have two models, Category and Post

Category is recursively looped to it self - it belongs to parent category and has many children categories. Beside it has many posts thus, that any category can has posts and many children categories which can have theirs own posts

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent_category, class_name: 'Category'
  has_many :children_categories, class_name: 'Category', foreign_key: 'parent_category_id'

  has_many :posts

  def all_posts
    # magic here
  end
end
```

I need implement *all_posts* method of *Category* thus it returns *ActiveRecord::Relation* that unites all posts that belong to the category and its children.

Thank you.

p.s. I use Rails 4.1.1 and Ruby 2.1.2 and PostrgreSQL 9.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def all_posts
  ids = [id]
  more_ids = [id]
  until (more_ids = self.class.where(:parent_category_id => more_ids).pluck(:id)).empty?
    ids += more_ids
  end
  Post.where(:category_id => ids)
end
```